# Wrong arguments zero or one error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have passed an argument to the controller action. But when loading the page it shows wrong arguments error. And also I need to configure my routes so that it will become users/id/requests instead of user/requests. Because of that I need to pass an user argument.

```
 <% if signed_in? %>
   <li><%= link_to "Requests", requestuser_path(current_user) %></li>
```

usercontroller:

```
 def requestuser(user)
   @title = "Requests"
   @users = user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users do 
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :requests, only: [:create]

 match '/request', to: 'users#requestuser', via: [:get, :post], as: :requestuser
```

Comment: Can you add in the full contents of the error?

Comment: When I switch to request tab in a page it invokes users controller and request user action it routes to  /request so I am not able to get the user id in params. So I pass the user argument but it shows wrong arguments (0 or 1) error

Answer (score 1):

> But when loading the page it shows wrong arguments error.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

You aren't supposed to pass any arguments to Controller methods. In this case you should get user through params:

```rb
# users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Requests"
  @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

---

> And also I need to configure my routes so that it will become users/id/requests instead of user/requests.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes

```rb
# routes.rb
resources :users do 
  member do
    get :following, :followers, :requests
  end
end
```

```rb
# users_controller.rb
def requests
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  # whatever requests are
  # @user.requests
end
```

This is what link should look like in view:

```
<%= link_to "Requests", user_requests_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: How can I access the user variable in show method from requests and what if I had another users variables in show method for example  @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page]).

Comment: Do you use any autthentication gems? If you are using Devise, currently logged in user is accessed through `current_user`
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers